# Show list of co-ordinates in google map using geolocation in html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

For a small school project I need something exactly like this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/b9qud/2/

So I created a html file test.html and added all the code of the fiddle like below. But when I open the html page in the browser I do not get any output. How can I make this work? Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="map"></div>

<script>

    var map;
var elevator;
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.950198, 151.259302),
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
};
map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], myOptions);
var markers = [];

var beaches = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (x in beaches) {

    var data = beaches[x];
    console.log(data)
    var lat = beaches[x][1];
    var lng = beaches[x][2]
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latLng
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    bounds.extend(latLng);
}

map.fitBounds(bounds)

new google.maps.Rectangle({
    bounds: bounds,
    fillColor: '#000000',
    map: map
})

var centerBounds = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: bounds.getCenter(),
    icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=C|FF0000|000000'
});

</script>
```

Comment: what errors are thrown in console?

Comment: ReferenceError: google is not defined

Comment: did you include library scripts? ... google maps an jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the **jQuery library** on your page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Include the **Maps API**:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

These 2 scripts are loaded by jsfiddle (they are defined in ***Frameworks & Extensions*** and ***External Resources***) in the side bar.

Next, wrap your code in a function and call that function when the DOM is ready.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {

    // your code goes here
}

$(function() {

    // Call the initialize function defined above
    initialize();
});

</script>
```

Put all that at the bottom of your html page, within the `<body></body>` tags.